# How to make Next.js do SSR (Server Side Rendering)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

To experiment with Next.js, I created an empty Next.js project, and added some code to fetch data for weather:

```js
export default function Home() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://api.weather.gov/gridpoints/MTR/84,105/forecast")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((d) => setData(d));
  }, []);

  const details = data && data.properties.periods[0];

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        Hello world
        {details && (
          <div>
            <h2>San Francisco Forecast</h2>
            <img src={details.icon} />
            <p>
              Temperature: {details.temperature}°{details.temperatureUnit} /{" "}
              {Math.round(((details.temperature - 32) * 50) / 9) / 10}°C
          </p>
            <p>{details.shortForecast}</p>
            <p>{details.detailedForecast}</p>
            <p>{new Date(details.startTime).toLocaleString()}</p>
          </div>
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-snow-6tvqc?file=/pages/index.js
and the standalone page: https://6tvqc.sse.codesandbox.io/

How can we make the following command

```
curl https://6tvqc.sse.codesandbox.io/
```

be able to show the content as if on the webpage? (so should be able to have `Temperature` and the numbers after it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do data fetching in [these](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching) functions.

Next.js provides 3 functions for data fetching. You have to export them from your page.

1. GetStaticProps - will only execute when you build.
2. GetServerSideProps - will execute on every request.
3. GetStaticPaths - to get dynamic paths for GetStaticProps, when you export this you have to export GetStaticProps also.

You have to return data in a format and it will be injected in props of your react component.

You can also provide fallback on props to dynamically render pages, like you don't have to make every page static (using GetStaticProps/Paths). Make only some of them and Next.js will make remaining on request and will cache them for next request.

Comment: could `GetStaticProps` be done in just a couple of minutes and if so, can you give an example?  I think just for the purpose of SEO it'd be sufficient

Comment: actually GetStaticProps is best for SEO, it will spit out html pages on build. When you run npm run build. it will be best you want to curl it. It does not work on development https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#runs-on-every-request-in-development you have to build first and then you can serve it from any CDN no server needed!

Comment: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#when-should-i-use-getstaticprops like mentioned here it will make html and JSON files from your react component,

Comment: what do you mean by could ```GetStaticProps``` be done in just a couple of minutes ?

Comment: like, can we add a couple of lines some where and it can already be working... but how can the server know whether to give a React page or to give generated content? It probably is by the browser type / spider crawler `User-Agent` isn't it

Comment: server knows which function you exported from component so if it only contains getStaticProps it will generate Html else in getServerSideProps it will call that function on every request then it will make html and send to client.  You can export different functions for each page.

Comment: interesting, I added `GetStaticProps()` and then the development server can already let me `curl` to http://localhost:3000/ and on Bash, I can see the temperature data... but not the generated page

Comment: Pages will be generated after you build , "npm run build"